# Can I create new Gmail ID with same mobile number?

Tags: gmail, google-account, mobile

Basically, I want to change my current Gmail address and associate my mobile number with new Gmail address (I created my current address years ago with not-so-professional ID).

Apparently, Gmail won't allow to create multiple addresses with same mobile number (you need to authenticate mobile number).

Is there any way I can achieve this (without switching to other email providers)?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure for mac, but for Android you can remove the phone number from old email and add to new email.

1. Open Setting
2. Google(setting)
3. Manage Google Account
4. Personal Info
5. Contact Info
6. Phone > Select your number (301112333...)
7. Click Dustbin symbol to delete
8. Select REMOVE NUMBER

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can remove your existing number on gmail and then you can add new number.

Comment: And how? I think it would be nice to write into your answer.

Answer (score -2):

Yes and No. It is not straight forward. If you have used a mobile phone to create business account with Google then you may be able to create multiple gmail ids using same mobile number, otherwise you may not create. There is a nice discussion thread, check it out

https://techoforum.com/t/how-many-google-accounts-you-can-create-with-one-mobile-number/164

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).